# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsapin

Tags: ubuntu, ld

I am trying to compile a code ( a simulator) by running its makefile in Ubuntu 10.04 but I get this error:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsapin

( there is a libsapin.a file in that simulator directory)

I've searched it and found lots of threads explaining the same problem but most of them have problems with compiling with OpenGL that isn't my issue. I would be grateful if anyone help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot link a library that has not been included into library paths with `-l`. Instead, you should use `-L` with the full path to the library (e.g. `-Lfile/to/my/libsapin.a`). You can find more information about linking from [swarthmore.edu](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_C_libraries.html).

Comment: Thank you for replying, I changed the config file as you told by using -L <directory> and it DID worked, but now facing this similar error:/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxed

Comment: by using `locate` command I find the libraries linked by `-l`, there was plenty of this kind of commands in config file which is called by makefile, now after all I see this error:`collect2: ld returned 1 exit status` I have no idea where the problem is!

Comment: You should start another question with your new information and problems.

Comment: I think may be it is connected with with `-l` command, there is 2 different paths for each library I fiound, for example to libsapin.a but I just put 1 directory in command using `-L`. I think maybe this caused the error, how can i put 2 directory using `-L`?